# How can I keep the order of duplicates in a vector after sorting it?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stable-sort

I have a vector of structs, each struct has a numerical ID that I am using to sort the vector items by. I want the IDs to be sorted, but to also appear in the order they did in the original vector after sorting. Let me explain...

Suppose you have a vector like this (ignoring the structs):

```cpp
vector<int> items = {
    1,
    2,
    5, // First 5
    8,
    9,
    6,
    5, // Second 5
    4,
    7,
    3,
    5, // Third 5
    10
};
```

After sorting I want the vector to look like this:

```cpp
vector<int> items = {
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5, // First 5
    5, // Second 5
    5, // Third 5
    6,
    7,
    8,
    9,
    10
};
```

Remember, these items would actually be structs. Multiple can have the same ID, but different values for the other properties. Right now, I don't think the structs have a predictable order after sorting. Is there a way to ensure this kind output? Could I add another property to the structs indicating their original order and somehow use that in the sorting algorithm perhaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're looking for [is called a "stable sort"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability), and the C++ standard library provides it as [`std::stable_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort); when items compare equal, they appear in the same order they appeared in the original data set. Plain `std::sort` makes no such guarantees (and can therefore use slightly more efficient algorithms for the sorting that won't preserve order for equal elements), but `std::stable_sort` requires the use of algorithms that *do* make that guarantee.

Comment: I was looking for a duplicate that basically said this. Surprisingly hard to Google. "sort container and keep duplicates in original order C++" kept popping up Stackoverflow hits on how to erase duplicates. I had to put in `stable_sort` into the keywords to get any marginally useful offerings. Which is pointless, because if you know to add `stable_sort`, why the <expletive deleted>  are you asking the question?

Comment: @user4581301: Yeah, I looked too. Found a bunch of questions where people misused `std::stable_sort`, but the closest to a "duplicate" was [What is the difference between std::sort and std::stable_sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23985891/364696), which sort of asks the question in reverse. This question knows what they want, but not what to call it, that question found the name "stable sort", and doesn't understand what it's doing. It's a mess. I'd happily dupehammer this if I found a good duplicate, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Hopefully what I did to the title will make this question bubble up more easily for the next asker.

Comment: @user4581301 There is [How to sort by module with saving the original order of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69098501/c-how-to-sort-by-module-with-saving-the-original-order-of-elements), but given how confused that question got, I'd be inclined to close it as a duplicate of this one rather than vice versa.

Comment: @JaMiT: Yeah, I found that one, but it was another "I found `stable_sort`, but I wrote an invalid comparator without strict weak ordering" question. The problem wasn't "I don't know what a stable sort is" or need it explained or never found `std::stable_sort`, it was "I'm misusing sorting, period".

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thank you so much for this answer! I was having a hell of a time trying to find anything about this on Google, as others have mentioned, it is hard to put into words.